# How can I implement Long press and Short press ? Long press should be 3 seconds long

Tags: c, algorithm, button, stm32f4discovery, long-press

I am working on STM32F407VG development board. I need to design a product by using that processor. My application includes SHORT PRESS and LONG PRESS functionality. I have implemented the Logic. But I don't know what is the issue.

I have used on board User Push button. I have used timer 6 and it generates interrupt after every 20mS. Can someone review the code and tell me  about the problem. I know I haven't added the debouncing. That also need to be added.

Currently When I press the button then my executes but it only goes in first if condition which is short press it doesn't handle the long press.

```
volatile uint32_t buttonPressTime = 0;
volatile uint8_t buttonPressed = 0;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);

#define SHORT_PRESS_THRESHOLD 50 // For example, 50 milliseconds
#define LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD 3000 // 3 seconds

int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();

 
  SystemClock_Config();

  /
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
 
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6); // Start Timer 6 with interrupts enabled
  

  
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      if (buttonPressed) {
                  if (buttonPressTime < SHORT_PRESS_THRESHOLD) {
                      // Handle short press
                      printf("Short Press");
                  } else if (buttonPressTime >= LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD)
                  {
                      // Handle long press
                      printf("Long presss");
                  }
                  buttonPressed = 0; // Reset flag
              }
  }
 
}
```

## Tim6 initialization

```
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 55;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 59999;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

## Call back Function is as follows

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == TIM6)
    {
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
        {
            buttonPressTime++; // Increment button press time
        }
        else
        {
            if (buttonPressTime > 0)
            {
                buttonPressed = 1; // Set button pressed flag
            }
            buttonPressTime = 0; // Reset button press time
        }
    }
}
```

My design application is basically to control the Brightness on single press and turn on/off the display using long press button. The long press duration should be around 2-3 seconds. Currently My code is just a basic code. I will add the functionalities later. When this part of project starts working correctly.

Comment: Why do you need `buttonPressed` flag? `buttonPressTime > 0` indicates that button is pressed. I think that the timer can just count `buttonPressTime`. And you may perform debounce check in the `while` loop. So in the button interrupt you starts the timer (if `buttonPressTime == 0`). Then in the main prog you check pin state and increment debounce counter if needed. After some debounce limit (or after long press threshold) you consider that pressing is over and stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you always set `buttonPressTime=0` whenever you set `buttonPressed = 1`

So when you test `if (buttonPressed)` the `buttonPressTime` is always 0.

I would try somethink like:

```
 /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
 while (1){ 
      if (buttonPressed) {
              if (buttonPressTime < SHORT_PRESS_THRESHOLD) {
                  // Handle short press
                  printf("Short Press");
              } 
              else if (buttonPressTime >= LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD) {
                  // Handle long press
                  printf("Long presss");
              }
              buttonPressed = 0; // Reset flag
              buttonPressTime = 0; // Reset button press time
       }
 }
```

---

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    if (htim->Instance == TIM6){
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0) == GPIO_PIN_RESET){
            buttonPressTime++; // Increment button press time
        }
        else{
            if (buttonPressTime > 0){
                buttonPressed = 1; // Set button pressed flag
            }
            //buttonPressTime = 0; // Reset button press time here leads to always buttonPressTime==0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Muhammad Haris: I added the modified code parts. [UNTESTED]